# Magento 2: How to insert the checkout & cart link in phtml?

Tags: magento2, template

Magento version: 2.0.0

I try to add the checkout & cart page link to the page header not the toplink, so what's the link of them?
I searched my question and got a solution that add a block into the default.xml, but I don't know how to use it in phtml file. so, how to use it?

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="my-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Cart</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">checkout/cart</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="my-link1">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Checkout</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">checkout</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>                   
            </block>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call  checkout & cart page link at phtml/block by below code without using layout xml

**For PHTML:**

*Checkout link:*

*`<?php echo $block->getUrl('checkout', ['_secure' => true]);?>`*

*Cart link:*

*`<?php echo $block->getUrl('checkout/cart', ['_secure' => true]);?>`*

**At block class:**

*Checkout link:*

```
$this->getUrl('checkout', ['_secure' => true]);
```

*and Cart link:*

```
$this->getUrl('checkout/cart', ['_secure' => true]);
```